# Regex Replace Escape character c#

Tags: c#, regex

**This is html:**

```
<font color="#000fff" size="1" face="Arial">Genuine Windows® 7 Home Premium (64-bit)</font>
```

**This is what I wanted to convert:**

```
[color="#000fff"]Genuine Windows® 7 Home Premium (64-bit)[/color]
```

**This is what I tried:**

```
var post = Regex.Replace(post, "<font color=\"([a-fA-F0-9\\#]+)\">(.*?)</font>",
                                 m => "[color=\"" + m.Groups[1].Value + "\"]" + m.Groups[2].Value + "[/color]");
```

Its not matching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because you haven't catered for the `size="1" face="Arial"`. Try this:

```
"<font color=\"([a-fA-F0-9\\#]+)\"[^>]*>(.*?)</font>"
```

(Note the addition of `[^>]*` to capture everything else in the opening font tag)

Comment: My God! How I cant see that part. Thanks. Will be marked in minutes

Answer (score 1):

Your fix is:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string post = "<font color=\"#000fff\" size=\"1\" face=\"Arial\">Genuine Windows® 7 Home Premium (64-bit)</font>";
    post = Regex.Replace(post, "<font color=\"([a-fA-F0-9\\#]+)\"[^>]*>(.*?)</font>", 
      m => "[color=\"" + m.Groups[1].Value + "\"]" + m.Groups[2].Value + "[/color]");
    Console.WriteLine(post);
  }
}
```

Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/mm9E3).

Answer (score -1):

**Update:** Performance bottlenecks fixed. See it [**in action**](http://regexr.com?320s0).

**Find:**

```
<font.*?color="([^"]*)"[^>]*>([^<]*)</font>
```

***Note:*** *This assumes color attribute will definitely exist.*

**Replace:**

```
[color=$1]$2[/color]
```

Comment: Due to performance you should use lazy operator in regex only when you have to, which is not this case, so you better stay with `[^>]*`